# CiviCRM Spark fees, database migration/export and cancellation

Tags: civicrm-spark

I need to cancel my monhtly fee as we have transfered to our server.
Can you tell me how to do this please.
I have tried to log in but says I have worng info to log in.
Also would like to know f the 18.48 monthly fee includes HST or not

Answer (score 1):

You can export your CiviCRM Spark database by going to Administer > Backups. This should be sufficient to get started on your own instance, but you may need to also download CiviCRM extensions (CiviCRM will display errors on the admin pages telling you which extensions are missing, most of which are not critical).

The monthly fees do not have any HST, since the service is run from the United-States (assuming that by HST you mean Canada's taxes?).

Once you are ready to cancel, there are links in the monthly renewal emails to allow self-serve cancellation.

Please do not hesitate to contact us at spark@civicrm.org for any billing or cancellation questions.